# PHP Form to mysql into two tables linked

Tags: php, mysql, forms, connection

I have been scratching my head at this for hours; new to PHP to please be kind.

I've tried multiple connection methods and some work some don't, but I would like to save into two tables at once from a single form, but with the second table having the first tables primary key as a foreign key.

For a reason I can not find, it just doesn't want to work and displays the second error message (fail). Any help would be greatly approached.

HTML Snippet - Please ignore the rubbish html

```
<form action="savedata.php" method="POST" >

                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Full Company Name</label>
                                            <input class="form-control" name="company_name" placeholder="For example - Aviva UK Zone PLC">
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Company URL(s)</label>
                                            <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="company_url" placeholder="Place a new domain on each line without http or www."></textarea>
                                        </div>
                                        <hr>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>POC Name</label>
                                            <input class="form-control" name="company_poc_name"placeholder="Point of contact name">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>POC Telephone</label>
                                            <input class="form-control" name="company_poc_telephone" placeholder="Point of contact telephone">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>POC Email</label>
                                            <input class="form-control" name="company_poc_email" placeholder="Point of contact email">
                                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                    <div class="panel panel-info">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                           New User Information
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <p>This user will be hard-paired with the company above; the user will not be emailed until you complete a dataset to the company.</p>  <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Full User Name</label>
                                            <input class="form-control" name="user_name" placeholder="Full User Name i.e. Joe Blogs">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Temp Password</label>
                                            <input class="form-control" name="user_password" placeholder="User Work Email Address">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>User Email</label>
                                            <input class="form-control" name="user_email" placeholder="User Work Email Address">
                                        </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>

                     <div class="panel panel-danger">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                           Complete New Company + User
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <p>The company and user will be created, you must then add a data set to pair with the company you have just created.</p>   <div class="form-group">
                                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block" value="Save new Company"></input>

                             </form>
```

PHP

```
    <?php mysql_connect("localhost","user","password");
mysql_select_db("corporat_account");


$order = "INSERT INTO corp_companies (company_name, company_url, company_poc_name, company_poc_telephone, company_poc_email)
VALUES ('$_POST[company_name]','$_POST[company_url]','$_POST[company_poc_name]','$_POST[company_poc_telephone]','$_POST[company_poc_email]')
INSERT INTO corp_users (comp_id, user_name, user_password, user_email) 
VALUES ('1','$_POST[user_name]','$_POST[user_password]','$_POST[user_email]')";

$result = mysql_query($order);  
if($result){
    echo("<br>Input data is succeed");
} else{
    echo("<br>Input data is fail");
}

?>
```

Comment: You don't want to be using **MySQL_*** for your queries any more. It's depreciated. Check out MySQLi or PDO. Also, you shouldn't put user data directly into a query like you have. You either need to escape it using [real_escape_string](http://uk3.php.net/mysqli_real_escape_string) or by using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) to prevent SQL injections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't use execute 2 queries together without using ";" to divide them. but let's divide it in php since we need to do it to get the comp_id first. we'll use [mysql_insert_id()](https://www.php.net/mysql_insert_id) which enables us to get last inserted table's generated id:

```
$order = "INSERT INTO corp_companies (company_name, company_url, company_poc_name, company_poc_telephone, company_poc_email)
VALUES ('$_POST[company_name]','$_POST[company_url]','$_POST[company_poc_name]','$_POST[company_poc_telephone]','$_POST[company_poc_email]')";

$result = mysql_query($order); 
$comp_id = mysql_insert_id();
$usersql = "INSERT INTO corp_users (comp_id, user_name, user_password, user_email) 
VALUES ('$comp_id','$_POST[user_name]','$_POST[user_password]','$_POST[user_email]')";
$result2 = mysql_query($usersql); 

if($result && $result2){
    echo("<br>Input data is succeed");
} else{
    echo("<br>Input data is fail");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that Volkan; I keep getting this error now - 

[05-Feb-2014 17:36:04 UTC] PHP Warning:  mysql_insert_id(): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /home/corporat/public_html/pushdata.php on line 13
[05-Feb-2014 17:36:04 UTC] PHP Warning:  mysql_insert_id(): A link to the server could not be established in /home/corporat/public_html/pushdata.php on line 13
 
I added in the connection details too the other two lines, but not sure how to work this one

$result = mysqli_query($con, $order); 
$comp_id = mysql_insert_id(); - LINE 13?

Comment: if you are using mysqli you should use mysqli_insert_id($con)

Comment: Thanks for that! Saved me another 24 hours of headache(s) - karma to you :)

Answer (score -2):

Unless you are using a bulk insert, your mysql query will not work properly the way you want it to.

You will just need to reuse your $order statement and make it into two.

```
$order = "INSERT INTO corp_companies (company_name, company_url, company_poc_name, company_poc_telephone, company_poc_email) VALUES ('$_POST[company_name]','$_POST[company_url]','$_POST[company_poc_name]','$_POST[company_poc_telephone]','$_POST[company_poc_email]')";
$result = mysql_query($order);
if($result) {
  // we are ok to complete the next step
  $order = "INSERT INTO corp_users (comp_id, user_name, user_password, user_email)  VALUES ('1','$_POST[user_name]','$_POST[user_password]','$_POST[user_email]')";
  $result = mysql_query($order);
  // We can check result here too if you want
}
```

So without using bulk insert, you cannot run both those inserts at the same time, you need to split them up. You can use the same connection.

Comment: If you want the key from the first table, you will need to query that table for what you just inserted to get that key

Comment: no, querying table for last inserted id would create problems since other clients might also be executing inserts on that table. just use mysql_insert_id() explained in my answer.